Cannot access function 'emitFile' from Webpack
I'm trying to use functions from the Webpack5, namely, 'emitFile' and 'rootContext'. However I'm not able to access them, returning me the following message 'Unresolved function or method'. I've imported apparently the needed packages:
const path = require("path");
const loaderUtils = require("loader-utils");
But still don't work...
This is the .js file were I'm trying to access 'emitFile' and 'rootContext' from Webpack5. However
the functions are marked as 'Unresolved function or method emitFile()'
function TranslationsLoader(content) {
    this.cacheable && this.cacheable();

    var options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);

    var name = options.name || "../translations/[name].json";
    var runtimePath = options.runtime || require.resolve("handlebars/runtime");

    var translationsInput = JSON.parse(content);
    [tag:var translationsPath = path.relative(this.rootContext || this.options.context, this.resourcePath);]
    var marketplaceTranslations = extractMarketplaceTranslation(
        translationsInput,
        translationsPath
    );

    var url = loaderUtils.interpolateName(this, name, {
        content: marketplaceTranslations
    });
   [tag: this.emitFile(url, marketplaceTranslations);]

    var compiledTranslations = compileTranslations(translationsInput);
    return `
    var Handlebars = require(${JSON.stringify(runtimePath)});
    module.exports = ${compiledTranslations};
  `;
}

module.exports = TranslationsLoader;


This is the Webpack.config hope it helps.The loader in question is the 'translations-loader'.
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      "./src/javascripts/index.js",
      "./src/stylesheets/app.scss"
    ],
    modal: [
      "./src/javascripts/modal.js",
      "./src/stylesheets/app.scss"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/assets"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/translations"),
        loader: "translations-loader",
        options: {
          runtime: "handlebars",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(handlebars|hd?bs)$/,
        loader: "handlebars-loader",
        options: {
          extensions: ["handlebars", "hdbs", "hbs"],
          runtime: "handlebars",
          inlineRequires: "/images/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib/loaders")]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules", path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib/javascripts")],
    alias: {
      app_manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/manifest.json")
    }
  }
};


I'm expecting to be able to use this function with Webpack context.
